# Confused on Neural Net gradient descend part in c++ code

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

I was planning to make my own neural net lib in C++, and I was going thru other people codes to make sure I am on right track... Below is a sample code, that I am trying to learn from..

Everything in that code made sense, except for the gradient descend part, in which he literally updating weights by adding with positive learning rate... Shouldn't we need to take negative of the gradient to reach the optima??

Line number : 137 - 157.

```
double Neuron::eta = 0.10;
void Neuron::updateInputWeights(Layer &prevLayer)
{
    // The weights to be updated are in the Connection container
    // in the nuerons in the preceding layer

    for(unsigned n = 0; n < prevLayer.size(); ++n)
    {
        Neuron &neuron = prevLayer[n];
        double oldDeltaWeight = neuron.m_outputWeights[m_myIndex].deltaWeight;

        double newDeltaWeight = 
                // Individual input, magnified by the gradient and train rate:
                eta
                * neuron.getOutputVal()
                * m_gradient
                // Also add momentum = a fraction of the previous delta weight
                + alpha
                * oldDeltaWeight;
// updating Weights
        neuron.m_outputWeights[m_myIndex].deltaWeight = newDeltaWeight;
        neuron.m_outputWeights[m_myIndex].weight += newDeltaWeight;
    }
}
```

Everything in there is just adding things for the weight updation, there is not negative sign in there.

https://github.com/huangzehao/SimpleNeuralNetwork/blob/master/src/neural-net.cpp

Good thing is it works fine, which is making me weird....

I asked this question to everybody I know of, they all got confused.

Here is the video representation of creating neural net lib... same code as above one.

https://vimeo.com/19569529

Comment: when `m_gradient` is the negative of the gradient then no `-` is needed in the code you posted.

Comment: simply add a `-` to see what happens. When you get wrong results you know that there should be no `-`. Mistakes of wrong sign happen all the time, you notice them and change the sign, I don't think there is much magic to it

Comment: how did you know that was negative of the gradient ? sorry i am beginner at this.. could you please elaborate ?

Comment: ohh so it is just trial and error approach ?

Comment: I dont know. You say you get correct results and `m_gradient` being the negative of the gradient is one possible explanation

Comment: this m_gradient calculation is same as everyone has been doing... but they all used negative learning rate

Comment: which confused me more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is indeed confusing but I think that the crux in this line. (I may be wrong but if you say that the training is working then the only line which could possibly alter the signs should be this.)

```
eta * neuron.getOutputVal() * m_gradient
```

where `neuron.getOutputVal()` provides the direction to the update.

Comment: ahh because tanh is ranging from negative and positive ?

Comment: is that true abhishek ?

Comment: could you please tell me how this line is telling direction to the update ?